# dataframe groupby - aggregate separately for each column

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to use different aggregate function for each column of the dataframegroupby object

Grouping dataframe by some field and aggregate some columns

```py
def aggregation(df):
  quorum = df.groupby("itemId")[['Xmin','Ymin', 'Xmax', 'Ymax']].median().reset_index()
return quorum


I want to make aggregation min() for 'Xmin','Ymin' fields and max() for 'Xmax', 'Ymax' ones. But don't know how to write desirable code...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def aggregation(df):
    return df[['itemId','Xmin','Ymin', 'Xmax', 'Ymax']].groupby("itemId").agg({'Xmin':'min','Ymin':'min','Xmax':'max','Ymax':'max'}
```

where Xmin, Ymin Xmax, Ymax are the respective column names

Comment: if Xmin and Xmax are the same column you can use 'X': ['min','max'] in the agg function dictionary